# CFD mesh generation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, mesh-generation

Is there any libraries(python is preffered) for generation rectangular 3d mesh (for using with the finite difference method), which will be consistent with boundaries? (I've asked this question at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170603/cfd-mesh-generation), but nothing)

Comment: What do you mean by the consistence of boundaries? The blockMesh utility of OpenFOAM offers good opportunities to create simple block meshes which should be suitable for FD methods as well. There are lots of examples e.g. in the tutorials provided by OpenFOAM or in the docu: http://www.openfoam.org/docs/user/blockMesh.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm partial to [gmsh](http://geuz.org/gmsh/), but it's more of a standalone tool rather than a library you can call from another program. Google directed me to [SALOME](http://www.salome-platform.org/), which does have proper python bindings, but again is mostly a standalone program. I haven't used it, but [OpenFOAM](http://www.openfoam.com/features/mesh-generation.php) has a mesh generator built in which might suit your needs.

There's a long list of mesh generation software [here](http://www.robertschneiders.de/meshgeneration/software.html), but you'll find that most of the 3D mesh generators are either (1) tetrahedral, (2) have weird licensing agreements under which you have to provide proof you're an American fruit bat over the age of 36 to get it, (3) no longer maintained, (4) are not free.

Answer (score -1):

I would only add to what Daniel Shapero said that gmsh can be used as both an executable and a library. It also has python bindings.

Comment: This would have been better as a comment to Daniels answer.

Comment: I would like to comment instead of posting a new answer, but scicomp.stackexchange is saying that I need to have reputation at least 50. My current reputation is 44. Curiously enough, I can comment on your comment. Don't ask me why.